# Identifying date in text file

Tags: date, text-files, identify

How can we identify or search, is there a any date in given text file( which contains huge numbers of data). considering all probable date format

Comment: What does the file in question contain, is it formatted or delimited if so how?

Comment: file contains log messages. actually it isn't formatted or delimited.there is multiple lines of log messages, which contains the IP ,MAC , date time, and many more info. I did others recognition, but m stuck at date which hasn't a any special format.

Comment: "all probably date format" is probably an unfeasible goal. In the log file you have, how many different date formats are there?